# How do animals lose heat?

Tags: zoology, heat

I remember being told as a child that dogs stick their tongue out to stay cool, because they can't sweat like us. This made sense to me.

But only a couple of days ago I suddenly thought: What about all the other animals?! I mean, I don't see a cat or a horse putting their tongues out, and yet I don't see them sweating either. How do they lose heat? How do different kinds of animals lose heat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways, which are briefly [summarized here](http://www.biosciweb.net/animal/pdf/thermo.pdf). I also recommend reading this nice [Scitable article](http://www.nature.com/scitable/knowledge/library/homeostatic-processes-for-thermoregulation-23592046) on thermoregulation. It is not too technical. [Felines do pant](http://activerain.trulia.com/image_store/uploads/5/0/0/8/1/ar131157178218005.jpg) when they get hot. [Horses do sweat](http://www.horsesaddleshop.com/signs-of-bad-saddle-fit.html#.VBRrTlbLx94). Jackrabbits can enlarge the [blood vessels in their large ears](http://bio1152.nicerweb.com/Locked/media/ch40/40_01Jackrabbit-L.jpg) to eliminate excess heat. Bird use a process called [gular flapping](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5d/BFAL_SOTE_shade.JPG/800px-BFAL_SOTE_shade.JPG), which is similar to panting of dogs and cats.  Animals can move into shaded areas.  The possible mechanisms are many.